# How to access keys-value from json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following information captured from a form, and the data is in json format (i believe?)

```
  var obj = {
        "schema":{
            "type":"object",
            "title":"Event Info",
            "required":[
                "name",
                "emergency_contact_name",
                "emergency_contact_no",
            ],
            "properties":{
                "name":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "minLength":3,
                    "maxLength":10
                },
                "medical_conditions":{
                    "title":"Medical Conditions",
                    "type":"string",
                    "maxLength":120
                },
                "emergency_contact_name":{
                    "title":"Emergency Contact Name",
                    "type":"string",
                    "maxLength":120
                },
               "emergency_contact_no":{
                    "title":"Emergency Contact Number",
                    "type":"string",
                    "maxLength":120
                }  
            }
        }
        }
```

So I would like to get the "required" fields only. I have tried obj['schema']['required'], and obj.schema.required, and obj['schema'].required, obj[0]['schema']['required'], obj[0].schema.required.
None of these works. How is it possible to easily retrieve the attributes that i want?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just `believe` we can't help you.What have you tried is absolutely correct.

Comment: Type `console.log(typeof obj)` and tell us the result.

Comment: sorry, i'm always confused about json, but i think it should be in json because it is enclosed by {} and key value is encoded in "". Could you enlighten me on this?

Comment: are you trying to do this in a async and sync context as that might be the only reason i foresee here , otherwise what you have tried is correct

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, I did the console.log(typeof obj), and the console returns it as string.

Comment: I tried to do var obj = JSON.stringify(obj); and the type is still string

Comment: @leo277, I post an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments, `console.log(typeof obj)` prints `string` and that means you need to convert your string to **javascript** object.

For this, you have to use `JSON.parse` method.

```
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
let required = obj['schema']['required'];
```

Comment: oh yes, it worked. I used JSON.parse(obj) as suggested. Thank you very much.